# Continuity of stochastic integration with respect to path

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let's consider the following question:
Let $(W_t,  t \in [0,1])$ be a standard Brownian motion and $f \in C[0,1]$ deterministic (or more generally $f \in L^2 [0,1]$). Define the stochastic process $(I_t, [0,1])$ by Ito integral
$$I_t = \int_0^t f(s) d W_s.$$ 
Is there always a continuous map $F: C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$, such that 
$(I_t, \ t\in [0,1]) = F((W_t,\ t\in [0,1])$? Note that this is true when $f \in C^1$, as we have integration by part formula:
$$I_t = f(t) W(t) - \int_0^t W(s) f'(s) ds.$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no, since the Ito calculus is generally only defined in the sense of $L^2$ convergence, but the general theory that goes into things like this is called rough path theory.